# Django models - normalization

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Say I have a **property** and it can be for **sale** and/or for **rent** (each with their associated price), how should I structure my models?

**A:**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    rent_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
```

**B:**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    (u'sale', u'Sale'),
    (u'rent', u'Rent'),
)

class Category(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
```

**C:**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)

class Rent(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
```

I think C would give me more flexibility if I'd like to add sale/rent specific fields. Structure B seems that it would be better for querying but I'm not sure.

Supposing I went with C, how would query a property that is on sale for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A is actually best if you can get by with it. Short of that, something like B would be okay. C is no good at all.

`Sale` and `Rent` are not objects, they're attributes of an object. Having them as models is horrid design.

Comment: I see where you're coming from - what sort of downsides do you see with A? Wouldn't this go against normalization?

Comment: Should sale_price be used to determine if something is on sale for example? I'd imagine that to be acceptable but would that still be the case if more than one sale related field is present?

Comment: No, it doesn't go against normalization. The idea of normalization is to separate data that will likely be used again, such as customer contact info on an invoice. However, the sale/rent price of an object will never be used for anything but that object. Therefore it belongs with the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with C, you may query properties on sale like this

```
properties = Property.objects.filter(sale__isnull=False)
```

This should work as in the Django docs :
[Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Remember that with this schema, you could have several rent or sale prices for only one property, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A better option might be to use Django's [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), which would look something like this:

```
class Property (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class SaleProperty (Property):
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)

class RentProperty (Property):
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
```

This results in the creation of three tables, but the tables of the sub-classed models don't duplicate any of the data from `Property`. Instead, they have an invisible foreign key that Django uses to treat the fields from the parent model as if they were present in the child model. You could then query `SaleProperty` when you're only interested in properties with a sale price, `RentProperty` for those with a rental price, or `Property` for **both**.